# To Pinpoint an error in Open Spread Sheet xml

Tags: xml, excel, spreadsheet

I am trying to create an Excel file using the XML spreadhseet version programmatically.. However i am facing some parsing errors.But the errors are such that i cannot pinpoint where is the problem exactly.

Is there a better parser,or a verifier or something like that for open Spreadsheet xml version?

Comment: The question is not clear enough. "A better parser": Better than what? What are you doing exactly and what kind of "Open Spread Sheet XML" are you talking about? There are multiple ones.

Comment: While opening the Open spreadsheet XML format in Microsoft excel i get an error saying there is a problem with the style segement. the end user wants better description than just getting there is a problem with the Style segment. I want where is the error exactly , in which line, which style segment specifically..

Comment: So you are talking about [Office Open XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML) for `Microsoft Excel`? This is not addressed to any "end user" but on programmers. So "the end user wants better description" does not matter. There is [Markup Language Reference](http://www.ecma-international.org/news/TC45_current_work/Office%20Open%20XML%20Part%204%20-%20Markup%20Language%20Reference.pdf) for programmers. Best chance you will have is creating a working `*.xlsx` file using `Excel` and then comparing this with your self created `*.xlsx` file on level of the single XML files in it.